# Parse Soap Response XML using Spring Batch

Tags: soap, spring-batch

How can I parse the SOAP response xml using Spring Batch. Creating bean for **org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader** and passring **fragmentRootElementName** parameter value as **XMLData** returned nothing, probably unmarshalling issue.

SOAP XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
<WSCorIDSOAPHeader xmlns="http://www.wilytech.com/" CorID="5A35F9B79906411A00156F9B91FFE1EB,1:1,0,0,wl-flor-apvm106|Tomcat|dorms106-1|WebServices|Client|http_//tempuri.org/|submit,2,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" />
    <To soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://fldcvpswa0806.something.com/RTPTransaction/SubmitTransaction.svc?wsdl</To>
    <Action soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ISubmitTransaction/Submit</Action>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:Submit xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RTPTransaction" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  <ns2:XMLData>
    <Creation>2016-03-09 02:10:00</Creation>
    <EndOfDays />
    <Transactions>
      <Transaction>
        <BusinessDate>2016-03-09</BusinessDate>
        <Items>
          <Item>
            <Extended>35.0</Extended>
            <Number>480000015523</Number>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Taxes>
              <Tax>
                <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                <Rate>0.000</Rate>
                <State>FL</State>
                <Type>N</Type>
              </Tax>
            </Taxes>
            <Unit>35.0</Unit>
          </Item>
        </Items>            
        <Stamp>2016-03-09 00:00:00</Stamp>
        <Store>01006</Store>
      </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
  </ns2:XMLData>
</ns2:Submit>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What was the result?  What was the configuration you used?

Comment: I am not sure how to generate XSD out of that SOAP XML? I am generating XSD for the XML considering XMLData as root element. 
`<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="step">
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="XMLData" />
  <property name="resource" value="path to soap.xml" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="tMarshaller" />
 </bean>

<bean id="tMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
  <property name="packagesToScan">
   <list>
    <value>package name</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>`

Comment: @MichaelMinella I tested out my code with sample valid XSD and XML and it worked. Now the only issue I guess is I am not generating valid XSD out of my SOAP XML file. How can I do that?